# How are arguments passed in small brackets processed in C?

Tags: c

For the following code:

```
int main(void) {
    int x = 1000, y = 5000;
    printf ("%d\n", x, y);
    printf ("%d\n", (x, y));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
1000
5000

Can somebody please explain this?

Comment: Duplicate of 2 questions.

Comment: @AntonH: How is it undefined behavior? Passing to few arguments to `printf` causes undefined behavior. If you pass to many arguments, the extra ones are evaluated and then discarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its about `operator precedence`.
in case of (x,y) first statement inside () is evaluated so the last value y is taken as result from (). without () all comma operators have equal precedence so evaluation takes from left to right so x value is taken for printf()

Answer (score 2):

Parentheses make `(x, y)` a single expression, composed of `x` and `y` with a [*comma operator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). The operator evaluates `x`, throws the value away, evaluates `y`, and make it the value of the expression.

Since evaluating variable `x` has no side effect, the expression `(x, y)` in this case is equivalent to `y` passed by itself:

```
printf ("%d\n", y);
```

Note: if your first `printf` used a `"%d %d"` format string, you would see both `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 1):

For the first printf, you are just passing a second argument that is being ignored.

For the second, you are invoking the comma operator which evaluates both it's arguments, and returns the value of the second.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing here is the evaluation of the C comma operator.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

The little used comma operator is often used within the third part of a `for()` loop to take multiple actions on increment, but technically it's a valid expression anywhere.

Comment: It's also commonly used in macro definitions.

Answer (score 0):

In the first call of function printf the number of arguments exceeds the number of format specifiers in the format string

```
printf ("%d\n", x, y);
```

In this case the second argument that is y will be ignored. Only x will be outputed. So the output of the call is

```
1000
```

In the second call of function printf there is only one argument that is an expression enclosed in parentheses.

```
printf ("%d\n", (x, y));
```

This expression is an expression of the comma operator. At first the first operand that is x is evaluated . Its value is ignored. And then  the second operand of the expression that is y is evaluated. Its value is used as the result of the full expression. So this function call outputs

```
5000
```